# Functions on generic arrays

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

I would like to use more functional programming in Swift. Some of the functions I write could work well on Arrays of various types. I don't want to rewrite the same function with different types (or typealiases.) The pattern how the function would work is often the same, just with different types. So, I tried something like this:

```
// Add indeces to an array of any type. I.e., returns an array of tuples of the array index and the original element.
func addIndeces<T: AnyObject>(toArray: Array<T>) -> Array<(index: Int, value: T)> {
    var arrIndex: [Int] = []
    for index in 0...toArray.count {
        arrIndex.append(index)
    }   
    return Array(Zip2(arrIndex, toArray))
}
```

When I call this function

```
// Note: reminderList is of type [Reminder]
let indexedReminderList = addIndeces(reminderList) as! [(index: Int, reminder: Reminder)]
```

I get a runtime error: "fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've copied your code but I don't get a runtime error. Instead there is a compiletime error where it says that I should change as! to as. So can you explain why you cast your result at all? One side note: you can just return Array(Zip2(Array(0..<toArray.count), toArray))

Comment: @Qbyte or even `Array(zip(indices(toArray), toArray))` or (only works with integer-indexed collections) `Array(enumerate(toArray))`

Comment: Thanks for the optimisations. I used them. However, the problem still exists. It needs to be 'as!' otherwise you get this error: 'Array<(index: Int, value: Reminder)>' is not convertible to '[(index: Int, reminder: Reminder)]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cast the tuple `Array` of type `[(index: Int, value: T)]` where `T` is of type `Reminder` to a tuple `Array` of type `[(index: Int, reminder: Reminder)]`. So you can see that the tuples have different element names (value and reminder) where both have different byte sizes - therefore the error.

So you should take the same element names for both tuples.

If you want to change the element names:

```
let newTupleArray = oldTupleArray.map{ (newElementName0: $0.0, newElementName1: $0.1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you are writing already exists – kind of.  `enumerate` "return a lazy `SequenceType` containing pairs (*n*, *x*), where *n*\ s are consecutive `Int`\ s starting at zero, and *x*\ s are the elements of `base`"

This means you can write your function as:

```
func addIndices<T>(toArray: [T]) -> [(index: Int, reminder: T)] {

    // if you want to label the tuple elements index: and reminder:,
    // you still have to use map:
    return map(enumerate(toArray)) {
        (index: $0, reminder: $1)
    }

}
```

Note, you don’t need to write `T: AnyObject` unless you *specifically* want to prevent this function from accepting anything other than arrays of classes (as that's what `AnyObject` is - the protocol that only classes, not structs or enums, conform to).

Note, `enumerate` only works for integer-indexed collections.  To make it more general, you could write `zip(indices(someCollection),someCollection))`.  `indices` returns a range of all the indices of any collection, so is equivalent to `someCollection.startIndex..<someCollection.endIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

The range `0...toArray.count` consist all elements form 0 to the count of toArray, including the count value, and in your case `arrIndex` will always have one more element then toArray. Thats what is causing different size error. To fix it replace your range with this one `0..<toArray.count`

Comment: I don't think that "size" is related to the size of the array rather than the actual byte-size of the type.

Comment: This is not fixing the problem.

Comment: @Qbyte Where exactly did it crash ? Just tried your code and its working like a charm

Comment: @Qbyte Sorry bro lately notice that you are not the OP